# Trying to get a solid Python install working on my Mac?

Tags: python, macos, unix, installation, buildout

I have Mac OSX 10.5.8 with Xcode installed. I want to avoid MacPorts and want to just get a solid Python install foundation so I can then move on to mess with Django and other things. I want to use Buildout with my Python applications.

I have installed binary Python 2.6.4 from the official site and installed this. Following other advice I have put this in my `~/.bash_profile` file:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

So, when I do a `which python` it shows `/usr/local/bin/python`. And, when I do a `python -V` it shows `Python 2.6.4` - this all seems great.

I've looked inside the `/usr/local/bin/` folder and, among other things, I seem to have the correct stuff pointing to Python 2.6:

```
python -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python
```

BUT, when I do an `easy_install` of virtualenv (that I want to use with Buildout) it seems to install it in `/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/virtualenv-1.4.3-py2.5.egg`

...which is Python 2.5? Also, when I setup my Buildout folder using virtualenv, in there the `.Python` symlink is going to:

```
.Python -> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Python
```

Why is this? I don't understand this. How can I get it all pointing to the correct Python 2.6?

Thank you so much for any answers, it's annoying the hell out of me. Cheers.

Comment: Note that **ActivePython** already comes with `virtualenv` .. and a package manager (`pypm install django` is all you need to run).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, there's absolutely no need to install a new version of Python to work on Django in Leopard. The stock Python 2.5 works absolutely fine, and Django is 100% compatible with that version.

Secondly, if you do want to use virtualenv with a different version of Python other than the system default, you simply need to tell it when you create the virtualenv:

```
virtualenv --python=/path/to/python/2.6 virtualenvname
```

Answer (score 1):

When you install a new Python instance, you also need to install a new copy of `easy_install` for it.  Follow the instructions for either the classic [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) version or the newer [Distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute).  In either case, for the python.org 2.6.4 on OS X the `easy_install` script will be installed in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin` which should come before `/usr/bin` on your shell `$PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, what I do is leave my system python completely as is.

I use the following to install 2.4, 2.5 and 2.6 versions of Python:

Use a buildout from the plone collective to get python2.{4,5,6} installed with easy_install and PIL (including libjpeg support)

Checkout the python buildout files from the plone collective. I like to put it in /home/dev/python-buildout

```
# svn co http://svn.plone.org/svn/collective/buildout/python /home/dev/python-buildout
```

Add a new local.cfg file into the src directory. This is where you specify what you want to build. Use the following in your buildout file:

```
[buildout]  
extends =  
  base.cfg  
  readline.cfg  
  libjpeg.cfg  
  python24.cfg  
  python25.cfg
  python26.cfg
  links.cfg  

parts =  
   ${buildout:base-parts}  
   ${buildout:readline-parts}  
   ${buildout:libjpeg-parts}  
   ${buildout:python24-parts}  
   ${buildout:python25-parts}  
   ${buildout:python26-parts}  
   ${buildout:links-parts}
```

Bootstrap with your system python and then run the buildout.

```
# python bootstrap.py  
# ./bin/buildout -c src/local.cfg
```

When everything has been compiled, you should have a new python binaries here:

```
/home/dev/python-buildout/src/python-2.{4,5,6}/bin/python
```

To use them, either add the bin directory to your path, or source the 'activate' script in the bin directory, which will set it as the active python in your current shell

```
daniel@madmax # which python   
/usr/bin/python  
daniel@madmax # python -V  
Python 2.6.1  

daniel@madmax # source /home/dev/python-buildout/src/python-2.4/bin/activate
(python-2.4)daniel@madmax # which python   
/home/dev/python-buildout/src/python-2.4/bin/python  
(python-2.4)daniel@madmax # python -V  
Python 2.4.6  

daniel@madmax # source /home/dev/python-buildout/src/python-2.6/bin/activate
(python-2.6)daniel@madmax # which python   
/home/dev/python-buildout/src/python-2.6/bin/python  
(python-2.6)daniel@madmax # python -V  
Python 2.6.4
```

For each project I'm working on, I tend to create a new virtual environment, using no-site-packages and the appropriate version of Python.

Answer (score 0):

PirosBOX:~ piros$ python -V
Python 2.5.1

Have OSX 10.5.8 and i write django apps fine :D
The important thing is to get the SVN release of Django, better!

Answer (score 0):

I found the following two links particularly useful when I had to do it:

http://jessenoller.com/2009/03/16/so-you-want-to-use-python-on-the-mac/

http://blog.captnswing.net/2009/04/19/python-mod_wsgi-64bit-mac-os-x-105/